# Kivy returns "Unable to find any valuable Window provider"

Tags: kivy

I have installed all dependencies from kivyOfficial website and I got no error but when I run the program

```
import kivy


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I get this error:

[image: this is error]

Comment: Have you tried running your program with the debug flag as suggested in the error output?

Comment: Hey John - just a quick bit of feedback on [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70722224/2). As a general rule we discourage please-help begging on the site, and edits that introduce words like "help" and "please" into the title tend to be rejected. (I wonder if the title amendment came from the question author, and it was just merged into your code block amendment by the Stack Overflow revision history?).